# Is there a synonym for 'idionymon'?

Tags: synonyms, legalese

Other than phrasal descriptions, such as "special illegal act"[1]?

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idionymon

Comment: In English law, this would be called *delictum sui generis* (as the Wikipedia article shows).

Comment: Have you looked in a thesaurus?

Comment: I did. It seems to be a coined term meaning just this one law. This is in essence a request for translation (off topic).

Comment: In the Greek, what are the parts of the word?

Comment: Official translations between the greek word are provided in many places, and are as Andrew says 'delictum sui generis' etc. From the Wikipedia source [1] it appears the 'idionymon' is used in English as a translation as well. I am not looking for a translation rather I am looking for synonyms which are not phrases.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is used to recognize a law, there is no synonym for it.